# Dynamically import components based on array item values

Tags: vue.js, components

I've got a single page app and im trying to import and render components based on what components exists in array(blockCount). Im storing several strings(component name) in said array.

```
Vue:
computed: {
    componentInstance () {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.blockCount.length; i++){
            return () => import(`@/components/${this.blockCount[i]}`)                    
        }
    }
},


Html:
<component v-for="component in blockCount" :is="componentInstance" />
```

So the issue im having is that the function stop at item[0] and just iterates that item. And im not quite sure how to iterate this function in a dynamic way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define a child component

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <component :is="componentInstance" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['componentName'],
  computed: {
    componentInstance() {
      return () => import(`@/components/${this.componentName}`)                    
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and render in parent:

```
<child-component v-for="(component, index) in blockCount" :key="index" :componentName="component"/>
```

Comment: This somehow freezes and crashes my client. No way of testing the results

Comment: None, it freezes before that.

Comment: Seems to be working. However im more inclined to have a solution without the need to create a child-component. Is this not possible?

Comment: At the beginning, I think we can use methods, but seem that it doesn't work. Not sure if there is a better solution.